# javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: @ManyToOne with joined columns

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I tried different approaches but i just can't figure out how to make this work. 
I have two entities: **Waggon** and **WaggonStation**, that are in a n:1 relation

```
@Entity
public class Waggon implements Serializable {

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        createdAt = new Date();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;

    private long waggonNr;
    private Date actDate;
    private boolean loaded;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
                         @JoinColumn(name = "stationIm",
                                     referencedColumnName = "im", insertable = false,
                                     updatable = false),
                         @JoinColumn(name = "stationNumber",
                                     referencedColumnName = "number",
                                     insertable = false, updatable = false),
                         @JoinColumn(name = "stationName",
                                     referencedColumnName = "name",
                                     insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    private WaggonStation station;
    private Double[] coordinates;
    private boolean mockData;
}
```

and

```
 @Entity
 public class WaggonStation implements Serializable {
      public DasWaggonStation() {
      }

      public DasWaggonStation(int im, int number, String name) {
          this.im = im;
          this.number = number;
          this.name = name;
      }

      @Id private int im;
      @Id private int number;
      @Id private String name;
 }
```

When i try to persist a list of Waggons

```
waggonRepo.save(waggonList); //CrudRepository<Waggon, Long>
```

I get the following Exception

> javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session :
>   [com.xx.xx.WaggonStation#com.xx.xx.WaggonStation@763568e4]

Can someone point me in the right direction? What am I missing?

The list i try to save contains these elements (neither Waggon nor WaggonStation contain any elements)

```
{
  "number": "218124714435",
  "actDate": "2017-04-14T02:55:00Z",
  "status": "HandedOver",
  "loaded": false,
  "station": {
    "im": 55,
    "number": 16352,
    "name": "aName"
  },
  "coordinates": [
    14.6073,
    41.1969
  ]
},
{
  "number": "218124714435",
  "actDate": "2017-04-13T20:05:00Z",
  "status": "Arrival",
  "loaded": false,
  "station": {
    "im": 55,
    "number": 16352,
    "name": "aName"
  },
  "coordinates": [
    14.6073,
    41.1969
  ]
}
```

Comment: The issue is most likely with how you construct and populate the modified entity. Post the code for that.

Comment: you are missing ID in waggonstation

Comment: @AlanHay I add a list to the empty tables, so the error occurs for the second element

Comment: @Sarief I use all 3 parameters as ids

Comment: Error makes sense then. You need to deal with the fact these 2 wagons point to the same station.

Comment: @AlanHay Yes, my hope was that the Framework would detect if there is already an instance of WaggonStation in the db and doesn't try to create a new one

Comment: Well it might if there was one in the database but there isn't. Try sending the 2 requests individually and see what the outcome of that is.

Comment: @AlanHay I tried, doesn't work. The error is different though: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "waggon_station_pkey"

Comment: the error is the same. it says that there is already an object with that id. same as in your stack trace. You need to properly qualify id. Hibernate requires it as part of specification.

Comment: alternatively, if you want to achieve what you want without id, you can play with CascadeType. But this will require additional work, since you will have to insert station manually first.